# How to specify DataContract in WCF with a referenced class

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a sample service class:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IViaCardService
{
 [OperationContract]
 InstantIssuanceCardProfile RetrieveInstantIssuanceCardProfileByID(Int64 Id);

[OperationContract]
Card RetrieveBlankCardForVisa(string dummyAccount);

[OperationContract]
Card RetrieveByPAN(string cardpan);
}
```

Implementing class:

```
public class ViaCardService : IViaCardService
{    

public InstantIssuanceCardProfile RetrieveInstantIssuanceCardProfileByID(Int64 Id)
{
    InstantIssuanceCardProfile cp = new InstantIssuanceCardProfileSystem().RetrieveByID(Id);
    return cp;
}

public Card RetrieveBlankCardForVisa(string dummyAccount)
{
    return new CardSystem().RetrieveBlankCardForVisa(dummyAccount);
}

public Card RetrieveByPAN(string cardpan)
{
    return new CardSystem().RetrieveByPAN(cardpan);
}
}
```

Now, the issue I have here is this: the classes `InstantIssuanceCardProfile` and `Card` are references added to the WCF Service Library (they are present in some other library. How do I now specify contracts for these two classes?

Comment: Interfaces are about behavior , why not create property in ViaCardService which get Card and InstantIssuanceCardProfile with [DataMember Name ="yourCard"]

Answer (score 2):

It might be a good idea to decouple your service contract from the third party library over which you don't have direct control. This will help to keep your interface fixed, even if you update the library or exchange it completely.

You can do this by using [Data Transfer Objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) to define your service contract. For example, define a new class `CardDto` which contains only those properties of `Card` that you want to expose in your interface. This class must be serializable to work with WCF.

When replying to a service call, map the `Card` instance you use internally in your service to the DTO type defined in the contract. You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org) to simplify these mapping steps.

Comment: that is a good idea... but for this case these classes, with many others I hope to user from the other library are many, and some of them have deep references with other classes. It's huge (this was an inherited project actually), so, I was kind of looking for an easier way out, than doing these things for possibly hundreds of classes.